# consitant interval timer (runnable results not sufficient)

Tags: timer, camera, runnable

We want to code a very accurate and consistent timer interval (100ms) to generate a periodic light pattern with the phone tourchlight.

Currently we use a runnable function, but this shows a lot of deviation.

If we measure the response with a photodiode we perceive deviations between 80 and even 150ms!

Is this error caused by the runnable function or the execution of the enable/disable of the Tourch function.

Comment: Can you add example code? Just the minimal code that you are executing.

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find the runnable that we used to trigger the phone tourchlight. The on/off period should be 100ms but is inconsistant variation of lenght and variation between on/off period. could this have to do with the camera service?

private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

```
    public void run() {
        if (mActive) {
            if (mSwap) {

                mSwap = false;
                mHander.postDelayed(mRunnable, 100);

                params = camera.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(params);

            } else {



                mSwap = true;
                mHander.postDelayed(mRunnable, 100);

                params = camera.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(params);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Please let us know if you need more information